# Recursive function to calculate the children of a parent

Tags: python, django, infinite-recursion

I have a set of data that looks like this:

> Person1 is the parent of Person2
>
> Person2 is the parent of Person3 and Person4
>
> Person3 is the parent of Person1

If I try to calculate the whole tree for Person1, the max recurssion will be exceeded and the program will terminate in an error. The expected result would be Person1 -> [Person2, Person3, Person4], so basically in the case the the calculation has to be repeated for an element that is already in the list, this has to be ignored. Do you have an idea, how could I solve this problem? My function looks something like this:

```
def compute_children(self):
    children = []
    children.extend(self.child)
    for child in children:
        temp = child.compute_children()
        if 0 < len(temp):
            children.extend(temp)
    return children
```

Comment: but is it a tree? if person2 -> person3 -> person1 -> person2? looks like a circular reference

Comment: Yes. It should be a tree, but there are cases where the data is not correct. That's exactly why the function fails and I want to find a way to avoid the error, without necessarily having to correct the data in the database.

Comment: ok, now I get it

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to create a collection containing your starting node when you call `compute_children` for the first time and before the loop that you have, add all the children to the collection, ignoring any child that has already found its way into the collection.

In graph-theory this kind of approach is usually referred to as coloring, that is, you store what nodes were already visited somehow, so in the future you will not revisit the same nodes if a cycle is present.